# Creating a WiFi hotspot on a Windows laptop without admin rights

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, hotspot

I want to share my laptop's internet:

- Windows 10 2018
- Version 1803

where I don't have admin privileges, creating a WiFi hotspot. Not having admin rights, I can't use the [built-in Mobile hotspot feature in the new Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027762/windows-use-your-pc-as-a-mobile-hotspot), nor I can install any third-party software. I searched the internet for some portable software that doesn't require admin rights to function, but I haven't been able to find anything so far.

I have a [TP-LINK TL-WN722N wireless USB adapter](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/usb-adapter/tl-wn722n/), and I remember in the past, I purchased this for this very specific reason, creating a local network and sharing the internet of my laptop.

However, I do not remember much now!

I would appreciate If you could help me know:

1. If it is possible to use the above hardware to share the internet of my laptop?
2. or if there is any software that I can install without having admin rights, preferably FLOSS<sup>1</sup> and portable.

Thanks for your support in advance.

---

<sup>1. FLOSS: Free, Libre, and Open Source Software</sup>

**P.S.** This question was originally posted [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/69745/70592).

Comment: It's not viewed as "best practice" to add "thanks" etc. in your question (see help and meta on how to ask questions). Also there is no benefit in the link to the other site, it's a closed question. And it's not clear that the abbreviation gets "explained" later, nobody uses footnotes here (except for links) (I didn't event notice it before I edited it out and put it back in later). I rather use my time to answer then to read difficult questions, try to make it as easy to read as possible, thanks! ;)

Comment: Dear @Albin , I appreciate your kind feedback and answer. I hope you consider that I'm not a novice SO user. I do not appreciate some of the policies and practices.

Comment: I considered, that's why I was explaining my edit. You might also want to consider using a spell/grammar checking software like Grammarly (grammarly.com - the basic version is free) you have quite a few formal mistakes as well (I corrected a few for you).

Comment: @Albin , that would be a nice edit. I would certainly appreciate that.

Comment: already done : )

Comment: sure thing, any comments on my answer?

Comment: @Albin no comments on your answer at this moment. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Why did you roll back the grammer and spelling corrections again? (you even asked for it yourself??!!)

Comment: @Albin I think it was a mistake. anyway, I fixed the typoes. thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have admin privileges you won't be able to install hardware drivers either. So unfortunately no, the device won't solve your issue... and even if you manage to install it will be just another WLAN-adapter so you will be back to where you are now (I assume you have a WLAN-adapter already installed).